# Why is Oracle Java 8 installation failing in AWS Ubuntu 16.04 AMI?

Tags: ubuntu, java, amazon-ec2

I am using AWS EC2 with ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Suddenly, I am facing an error when I am trying to install Oracle java 8.

```
add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java -y
aptitude update -y
echo oracle-java8-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | sudo /usr/bin/debconf-set-selections
aptitude install oracle-java8-installer -y

The following partially installed packages will be configured:
  oracle-java8-installer
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
Setting up oracle-java8-installer (8u144-1~webupd8~0) ...
Using wget settings from /var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer/wgetrc
Downloading Oracle Java 8...
--2017-10-19 18:42:30--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u144-b01/090f390dda5b47b9b721c7dfaa008135/jdk-8u144-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)... 23.215.130.114, 23.215.130.99
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|23.215.130.114|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u144-b01/090f390dda5b47b9b721c7dfaa008135/jdk-8u144-linux-x64.tar.gz [following]
--2017-10-19 18:42:31--  https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u144-b01/090f390dda5b47b9b721c7dfaa008135/jdk-8u144-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)... 96.6.58.35, 2600:1408:17:188::2d3e, 2600:1408:17:186::2d3e
Connecting to edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)|96.6.58.35|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u144-b01/090f390dda5b47b9b721c7dfaa008135/jdk-8u144-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1508438671_73b5cc5baf26df8633a02d561a0ad83e [following]
--2017-10-19 18:42:31--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u144-b01/090f390dda5b47b9b721c7dfaa008135/jdk-8u144-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1508438671_73b5cc5baf26df8633a02d561a0ad83e
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|23.215.130.114|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2017-10-19 18:42:31 ERROR 404: Not Found.

download failed
Oracle JDK 8 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java8-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java8-installer
```

My ami is:

> ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-xenial-16.04-amd64-server-20171011
>   (ami-49426e2c)

It has been working for last few months and the issue has started since today. Does any have idea why it is happening and what is the workaround? Please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: It's happening because Oracle just released new versions (151 and 152) and PPA apparently hasn't been updated. Crossdupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46815897/jdk-8-is-not-installed-error-404-not-found  and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46800059/java-install-fails-on-ubuntu-14 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46808251/install-jdk-with-apt-get-on-ubuntu-precise-64